# Unified superscript exponent for vAxis numbers in Google Visualization (similar to Matlab charts)

Tags: google-visualization, number-formatting, scientific-notation

I'm referring to the Matlab chart here:
[matlab-chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326894/force-exponential-format-of-ticks-like-matlab-does-it-automatically)

Is it possible to get this kind of Unified superscript exponent for vAxis numbers in Google Visualization?

Even if the unified exponent for all ticks is not possible, is it possible to get superscripted exponent for the vaxis tick labels?
I've tried the methods described here: 
[GV-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204678/how-to-format-numbers-in-google-api-linechart/18204679)

While it does produce ticks in scientific format, it's a dirty format like this:
1.0E05

Is it atleast possible to change this to "1.0<sup>+5</sup>"?

Comment: not possible out of the box, but you can manually change the labels on the chart's `'ready'` event, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44765057/5090771) -- just need a way to isolate the vAxis labels, most likely using an attribute --> `text-anchor="end"`

Comment: Thanks @WhiteHat. Got it done!